# App_Code compilation does not clean old assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors

We are developing an ASP.NET Website with a whole lot of code in the App_Code folder due to a special customer requirement (I know, we don't like that either).

The project is using .NET 4.7.1 and we have the following compiler section in our web.config

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
```

After recompilation we often have the issue, that not all code seems to be cleanly recompiled, which breaks our login among other things. I was able to track the problem down in the following line:

```
    bool isAuthenticated = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated // User is logged in
                            && System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is JWTAuthenticationIdentity;
```

The second part of the check returns false in this case, even though both are of the same type, however, the type of the Identity is defined in "Assembly1" while the type of the JWTAuthenticationIdentity is defined in "Assembly2". Therefore casting between the two types is impossible.

The error can be fixed, by applying a random change in the web.config or so, to force the server to recompile. Afterwards, the old assemblies are usually deleted, both types are therefore defined in the same assembly again and everything works as expected again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my issue can be fixed, by disallowing the overlapping rotation of App_Pools in IIS.

This can be set via the IIS Manager GUI under "App Pools" --> "Advanced Settings" --> "Disable overlapping Recycle"